# load multiple tab contents in view pager without getting it again

Tags: android, json, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-json

i have a view pager in tabLayout that getting it's content from a JSON 
each page has differ contents 
all i want to do is to get each page content once 
is there a way to do this 
thanks in advance

Comment: i want to know a public way to do this , my code is complicated so don't ask about code. tnx

Comment: Store your JSON object/ array and get values from it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. My answer is not from an official source but it's from my previous experience.

Create your ViewPager as a member of the Activity:

`private ViewPager pager;`

Then inside `onCreate()` method, initialize your ViewPager:

`pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);`

Initialize your tablayout and and a tab selected listener:

```java
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(
                new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                        switch (tab.getPosition())
               {
                   case 0:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(0,true);
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(2,true);
                       break;

               }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                     switch (tab.getPosition())
               {
                   case 0:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(0,true);
                       break;
                   case 1:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
                       break;
                   case 2:
                       pager.setCurrentItem(2,true);
                       break;

               }

                    }
                }
        );
```

Set the an adapter to your ViewPager:

`pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));`

Create a private inner class `MyPagerAdapter` that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```java
private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
    private Tab1 tab1;private Tab2 tab2;private Tab3 tab3;

    //Tab1,Tab2,Tab3 representing your respective fragments
        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            //initialize all your fragments at once inside the constructor
            tab1=new Tab1();
            tab2=new Tab2();

            tab3=new Tab3();


        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {

//Return each fragment according to a position
            switch (position)
            {
                case 0:

                    return tab1;
                case 1:

                    return tab2;
                case 2:

                    return tab3;

            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

That's how I handled my case. Good coding.